# Wordpress core auto update fails for UpdraftPlus WordPress Backup Plugin

Tags: automatic-updates

I use a plugin ([Companion Auto Update](https://wordpress.org/plugins/companion-auto-update/)) for auto-update plugins.
[This is using the core function of Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/updraftplus-backup-restore-is-not-autoupdating/page/2/#post-11129722) where you can force auto-update for plugins.

All the plugins is updated when an update is available except [UpdraftPlus WordPress Backup Plugin](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/)

This has been tested by me but also by the plugin author of ([Companion Auto Update](https://wordpress.org/plugins/companion-auto-update/)) [see here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/updraftplus-backup-restore-is-not-autoupdating/page/2/#post-11017962).

I am on a VPS. I tried different server settings but seems this is not solving the issue.

I am asking why if i update manually all is done very fast (less than 2 minutes) and the auto-update of Wordpress seems to be unable to update automatically UpdraftPlus WordPress Backup. When Wordpress update his version i suppose is more bigger than 7 MB who is the size of UpdraftPlus WordPress Backup.

PHP error has to say:

```
wp-cron.php' (request: "POST /wordpress/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=***7500") execution timed out (120.770567 sec), terminating
```

[I tried some server settings changes](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/unable-to-auto-update-this-plugin/#post-11133224) but this doesn't help.
Any idea why there is this issue and how can be solved? Can be a Wordpress auto-update process issue?

Comment: Pretty sure that's a paid plugin that needs to be downloaded manually &/or have an api-key setup in order to update.

Comment: The plugin is free also if there is a paid version. Umh... can have an api key to stop automated update? But when i log into Wordpress i just press manually update and the plugin is updated... so the same should happen with the automated update.

Comment: Could be permissions on the server where it is hosted. Can you FTP? Download new from distributor & upload to replace?

Comment: Is not a permission issue on the server. I never had problem with other plugin. Unistall and reinstall the plugin doesn't help to solve :) thanks anyway for the suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment i enabled the plugin auto update from the settings of UpdraftPlus WordPress Backup Plugin.

This seems solve the issue with the auto-update of this plugin so maybe they are using a special API. If the settings of auto update is not enabled Wordpress or external plugin will be unable to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the plugin includes SDKs for various cloud storage, which makes it too large for WordPress to carry out an auto update for it.

What's the specific cloud storage do you use for backup? or do you just back up to your VPS? Maybe you can consider turn to an alternative that comes with support for your cloud option but is normal in size, you can check out this one: [WPvivid Bakcup/Restore](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpvivid-backuprestore).

Comment: I use to store 4 local backup uploaded also on the cloud. I use Google Drive and also keep 4 local backups. The plugin suggested seems to be new with just few installation.

Comment: Yes. it's a new plugin but is pretty neat to back up to Amazon S3, FTP/SFTP and local server. Unfortunately, it does not support Google Drive yet.